# Can I feed ARKit facial capture pre-recorded videos?

Tags: ios, video, arkit

I know a similar question has been asked before, but I have a very specific use case and thought I might put more details here.

I'm not an iOS dev, but very curious about the ARKit -- specifically want to test out the facial capture (tracking facial expressions) using ARKit [ARFaceAnchor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arfaceanchor).

I want to know if it is possible to feed pre-recorded videos to ARKit instead of the camera feed.
I did find an article with sample code here about using "sensor replay".

https://github.com/ittybittyapps/ARRecorder/tree/master/ARRecorder

https://www.ittybittyapps.com/blog/2018-09-24-recording-arkit-sessions/

Unfortunately it is not possible ship an app this way.

I know that the facial capture doesn't necessarily require depth sensor data (I've tried it by holding up the camera to a pre-recorded face on a monitor).
So I'm curious to know if anyone knows of a way to feed a static, pre-recorded video to the ARKit?

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: Any leads on this?